# Required to sign Paid Applications Agreement to enable initial IAP testing on iOS?

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm developing a iOS app containing in-app purchases. 
I'm having problems testing the app because it can't download IAP products from iTunes. Do I need to sign the Paid Applications Agreement even to perform initial (local) testing?

Answer (score 0):

To test the purchase add one `user` / `email ID` which is not an `apple ID` under `User and Groups` >> `Sandbox Account` in iTunes account.

Refer below screenshot for the same

[image]

and If you are not able to get the `IAP products`  from `iTunes` try this link and check wheather the store is working for you.

https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt?uo=8&at=11ld4k

if the link responsd with status code its working.

Comment: Done, but the problem is the app downloads invalid IAP products. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296289/test-in-app-purchase-on-iphone-before-app-submit) where problem is described in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after signed the Apple Paid Applications contract.